# How to drop few label from a column using dataframe.drop()

Tags: pandas, csv, label, row, drop

`df = pd.read_csv("idx.csv")` was used to read the data;  following is the data

```
         activity   time_s   lw_x   lw_y  ...   la_z   ra_x   ra_y   ra_z
72920          2   729.21 -1.273 -0.465  ...  0.094  1.555  0.676  0.543
72921          2   729.22 -1.430 -0.488  ...  0.094  3.078  0.977  1.996
72922          2   729.23 -1.559 -0.465  ...  0.078  3.445  2.590  2.266
72923          2   729.24 -1.609 -0.422  ...  0.066  0.066  2.652 -0.102
72924          2   729.25 -1.594 -0.352  ...  0.059 -1.723  0.945 -1.156
74552          3   745.53 -1.176 -0.828  ...  0.090 -0.082  1.223  0.148
74553          3   745.54 -1.176 -0.863  ...  0.090 -0.090  1.242  0.137
74554          3   745.55 -1.250 -0.813  ...  0.086 -0.086  1.246  0.105
74555          3   745.56 -1.332 -0.797  ...  0.094 -0.074  1.246  0.059
74556          3   745.57 -1.383 -0.777  ...  0.094 -0.066  1.238  0.023
82045          1   820.46 -0.512 -1.320  ...  0.145 -0.574  0.570 -0.031
82046          1   820.47 -0.563 -1.352  ...  0.102 -0.527  0.715 -0.004
82047          1   820.48 -0.617 -1.359  ...  0.063 -0.496  0.930  0.195
82048          1   820.49 -0.660 -1.352  ...  0.066 -0.469  1.051  0.242
82049          1   820.50 -0.711 -1.336  ...  0.055 -0.313  1.215  0.344
82205         77   822.06  0.641 -1.434  ...  0.082 -0.168  0.996  0.102
82206         77   822.07  0.887 -1.434  ...  0.078 -0.168  0.996  0.102
82207         77   822.08  1.027 -1.383  ...  0.078 -0.168  1.000  0.102
82208         77   822.09  1.156 -1.246  ...  0.078 -0.168  1.004  0.109
82209         77   822.10  1.527 -1.012  ...  0.078 -0.172  1.008  0.117
100795        99  1007.96  0.000  0.000  ... -0.980  0.684  0.242 -0.734
100796        99  1007.97  0.000  0.000  ... -1.008  0.684  0.234 -0.738
100797        99  1007.98  0.000  0.000  ... -0.996  0.684  0.230 -0.730
100798        99  1007.99  0.000  0.000  ... -0.996  0.688  0.227 -0.730
100799        99  1008.00  0.000  0.000  ... -0.984  0.684  0.227 -0.734
```

I tried

```
df2 = df.drop(axis=0, index=["77","99"])
```

but showed following error

```
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:6644 in drop
    raise KeyError(f"{list(labels[mask])} not found in axis")

KeyError: "['77', '99'] not found in axis"
```

Kindly, would you please suggest a relevant solution to remove  77, 99 label from activity column if possible at your convenience time? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

77 and 99 are not part of the index but of the "activity" column. First you need to resolve their index:

```
>>> df.drop(df.index[df['activity'].isin([77, 99])])
       activity  time_s   lw_x   lw_y   la_z   ra_x   ra_y   ra_z
72920         2  729.21 -1.273 -0.465  0.094  1.555  0.676  0.543
72921         2  729.22 -1.430 -0.488  0.094  3.078  0.977  1.996
72922         2  729.23 -1.559 -0.465  0.078  3.445  2.590  2.266
72923         2  729.24 -1.609 -0.422  0.066  0.066  2.652 -0.102
72924         2  729.25 -1.594 -0.352  0.059 -1.723  0.945 -1.156
74552         3  745.53 -1.176 -0.828  0.090 -0.082  1.223  0.148
74553         3  745.54 -1.176 -0.863  0.090 -0.090  1.242  0.137
74554         3  745.55 -1.250 -0.813  0.086 -0.086  1.246  0.105
74555         3  745.56 -1.332 -0.797  0.094 -0.074  1.246  0.059
74556         3  745.57 -1.383 -0.777  0.094 -0.066  1.238  0.023
82045         1  820.46 -0.512 -1.320  0.145 -0.574  0.570 -0.031
82046         1  820.47 -0.563 -1.352  0.102 -0.527  0.715 -0.004
82047         1  820.48 -0.617 -1.359  0.063 -0.496  0.930  0.195
82048         1  820.49 -0.660 -1.352  0.066 -0.469  1.051  0.242
82049         1  820.50 -0.711 -1.336  0.055 -0.313  1.215  0.344
```

Shortcut without `drop`:

```
# Note the ~ to inverse the boolean mask True -> False and False -> True
>>> df[~df['activity'].isin([77, 99])]
       activity  time_s   lw_x   lw_y   la_z   ra_x   ra_y   ra_z
72920         2  729.21 -1.273 -0.465  0.094  1.555  0.676  0.543
72921         2  729.22 -1.430 -0.488  0.094  3.078  0.977  1.996
72922         2  729.23 -1.559 -0.465  0.078  3.445  2.590  2.266
72923         2  729.24 -1.609 -0.422  0.066  0.066  2.652 -0.102
72924         2  729.25 -1.594 -0.352  0.059 -1.723  0.945 -1.156
74552         3  745.53 -1.176 -0.828  0.090 -0.082  1.223  0.148
74553         3  745.54 -1.176 -0.863  0.090 -0.090  1.242  0.137
74554         3  745.55 -1.250 -0.813  0.086 -0.086  1.246  0.105
74555         3  745.56 -1.332 -0.797  0.094 -0.074  1.246  0.059
74556         3  745.57 -1.383 -0.777  0.094 -0.066  1.238  0.023
82045         1  820.46 -0.512 -1.320  0.145 -0.574  0.570 -0.031
82046         1  820.47 -0.563 -1.352  0.102 -0.527  0.715 -0.004
82047         1  820.48 -0.617 -1.359  0.063 -0.496  0.930  0.195
82048         1  820.49 -0.660 -1.352  0.066 -0.469  1.051  0.242
82049         1  820.50 -0.711 -1.336  0.055 -0.313  1.215  0.344
```

Comment: Hi Corralien, thank you for your response and suggestion. But when tried the provided code, it showed following error.

Comment: df2 = df[~df["activity"].isin[77, 99]]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [10] in <cell line: 1>
    df2 = df[~df["activity"].isin[77, 99]]

TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable   ... Kindly, will you suggest any other efficient ways to remove the 77, 99 from activity columns? Thanks

Comment: You forgot `( )` around `isin`. Copy/Paste the code. `df2 = df[~df['activity'].isin([77, 99])]`

Comment: Perhaps, you will need to change `77` to `'77'` and `99` to `'99'` if activity is a string and not integer.

Comment: It's not `isin[77, 99]` but `isin([77, 99])`!

Comment: Corralien, thank you.  when tired this df1 = df[df["activity"].isin(["77", "99"])]; then df1.head() ;  the output showed Empty DataFrame
Columns: [activity, time_s, lw_x, lw_y, lw_z, lh_x, lh_y, lh_z, la_x, la_y, la_z, ra_x, ra_y, ra_z]
Index: []; cordially, will you please explain how does this happen if possible, and suggest some other means to drop  77, 99  from  activity column? Thanks

Comment: Can you please try `df[~df['activity'].isin([77, 99])]` or `df[~df['activity'].isin(['77', '99'])]`. Just copy/paste.

Comment: Corralien, thanks a lot. Both worked!! Have a nice day !!!